# Website in codeigniter with blog and forum

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, phpbb

I have a requirement where in I need to create a website with registrations and login for end Users and Vendors. Using the same login they should be able to post comments on blog and forum too. Client wants to use Codeigniter 3.0.

Blog will be tentatively Wordpress based and forum will be PHPbb.

Should the blog and forum be something like Dove / Pyro etc which are based on CI?

Comment: You should look at this https://github.com/AdwinTrave/A3M

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang1983 I will check it out